# Turn off fast-forward merging for regular merge, but not for pull

Tags: git, git-merge, fast-forward

I want git to always make merge commits (`--no-ff`) when I use `git merge`, but keep the default behavior (`--ff`) for `git pull`. Is this possible (with configs)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two configs which might help are:

```
merge.ff
```

(From [`git merge` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)):  When set to `false`, this variable tells Git to create an extra merge commit in such a case (equivalent to giving the `--no-ff` option from the command line).

```
pull.ff
```

(from the [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))

Setting `pull.ff` to `true` would keep the default behavior where Git does not create an extra merge commit when merging a commit that is a descendant of the current commit.

To be tested: does `pull.ff` takes precedence over `merge.ff`?

```
git config pull.ff only
git config merge.ff false
```

As mentioned by [Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498594/kelvin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419475/6309) and confirmed by [`git-pull.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce1d3a93a6405b8a0313491df3099919ed3d150f/git-pull.sh#L58-L64), '`only`' is the value to use, not '`true`'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks like `merge.ff` takes precedence.

Comment: @oyvind You could workaround the issue by using an alias instead of a "bare" `git pull` which points to `git pull --ff`. But please don't call it `git puff`.

Comment: It might *appear* as though `merge.ff` is taking precedence, but I think what's actually happening is that `true` isn't a valid value (the man page doesn't mention `true` as a possible value). The invalid value causes the option to become unset, causing fallback to the current `merge.ff` behavior. `merge.ff` doesn't seem to override `pull.ff` because if you set the latter to `only` it takes effect just fine. I'm actually somewhat annoyed that `true` isn't equivalent to passing `--ff`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my tentative workflow (Note that the `pull.ff` config option only works on git 2.x.).

Use this config:

- Set `merge.ff` to `false`. This defaults the `merge` behavior to `--no-ff`.
- Set `pull.ff` to `only`. This defaults the `pull` behavior to `--ff-only`.

That means if you try to `pull` a branch where your local is both behind & ahead of the remote, the `pull` will fail. In that case, do a `rebase` so you're not behind any more.

Note:

I tried setting `pull.ff` to `true` but git seems to treat it as though the option is entirely unset. Note that the man page doesn't mention that `true` is a recognized value.

Comment: Well spotted. +1. I have amended my own answer accordingly.