# How to push but not pull changes when synchronize icon is clicked in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I click on Sync changes I want GIT to push my changes without pulling new changes.

**How can I change this behaviour in VS Code?**

Below is provided image of what button behaviour I want to change.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how the VSC Git integration works, but just came here to say that this is a terrible idea

Comment: I've somehow done this on my MacOS but can't do it on Windows / I forgot how to do it.

I once found some git issue on this but can't find it anymore. There has also been huge debate why this is good or bad.

I've been working like this for the past 3years and had no problems so now I want to set such behaviour on my Windows too.

Comment: Referring to this? [VScode git sync is breaking due to git pull in git 2.29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914928/vscode-git-sync-is-breaking-due-to-git-pull-in-git-2-29) The suggested solution is to update Git

Comment: Also for for future people that want same behaviour. Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624847/turn-off-fast-forward-merging-for-regular-merge-but-not-for-pull)